# How to create a custom year with different months?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to make a year as 1 April to 31 March with c#. If a Person input his DOB, the year changes if cross 31 March.`

```
//Display Window Period
DateTime winst21 = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, dob.Month, dob.Day);
DateTime wind21 = winst21.AddYears(1);
        
Label2.Text = "Your Current IPPT Window is " + "  " + winst21.ToString("dd/MM/yyy") + "  " + "-" + "   " + wind21.ToString("dd/MM/yyy");
```

Comment: You would probably need to implement a custom [calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar?view=net-5.0) class and pass it to [this `DateTime` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Globalization_Calendar_).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just an offset of +9 or -3 months:

```cs
//Display Window Period
DateTime winst21 = new DateTime(dob.AddMonths(9).Year, dob.Month, dob.Day);
DateTime wind21 = winst21.AddYears(1);
```